# Python: Prepend foldername to filename

Tags: python, directory, filenames

So I've been working on this for quite a while now..

The incoming mail (paper) is scanned using a Xerox WorkCentre.

On the screen we select the matching scan folder for any customer/vendor (4 digit number).

So any invoice by vendor x is stored in a specific folder.

Now we'd like to rename the pdf-file by prepending the matching customer-ID (4 digits) to the file, which happens to be the name of the parent folder where the pdf is stored in.

On our server we have a folder structure where all the scans are stored like this:

S:/Scan/[4 digit number]/filename.pdf

e.g. S:/Scan/9020/

where the contents is like

doc_12345.pdf
doc_12346.pdf
[...]

Now I'd like to prepend the parent folder name to any file like this:

S:/Scan/**9020**/doc_12345.pdf becomes S:/Scan/9020/**9020**_doc_12345.pdf

S:/Scan/**9021**/doc_12346.pdf becomes S:/Scan/9021/**9021**_doc_12345.pdf

After the file has been renamed, it should be moved to a common folder like:

S:/Scan/Renamed/

I would appreciate any ideas :)

Comment: Please, add your ideas of code first. It is not a Fiverr service here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it species a problem without giving code attempting to implement a solution. That way  the initial problem remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
import glob
import pathlib

inp_dir = 'S:/Scan/'
out_dir = 'S:/Scan/Renamed/'
folder_list = [i for i in pathlib.Path(inp_dir).iterdir() if i.is_dir()]
for cust in folder_list:
    flist = glob.glob(str(cust) + '/*.pdf')
    flist = [pathlib.Path(i) for i in flist]
    for file in flist:
        new_name = f'{cust.name}_{file.name}'
        os.rename(str(file), f'{out_dir}{new_name}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil

source = 'S:/Scan/Source/'
target = 'S:/Scan/Renamed/'


for dpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(source):
    for f in fnames:
        n = dpath.rsplit('/',2) [-1]
        
        os.chdir(dpath)
        if not f.startswith(n):
            
            os.rename(f, f.replace(f, n+'_'+f))
            nf = dpath+"/"+n+'_'+f
            
            shutil.move(nf, target)
```

That's what I've got so far.
Seems to work.